# How to preprocess all calls?

Tags: python, bottle

I use `bottle.route()` to redirect HTTP queries to appropriate functions

```
import bottle

def hello():
    return "hello"

def world():
    return "world"

bottle.route('/hello', 'GET', hello)
bottle.route('/world', 'GET', world)
bottle.run()
```

I would like to add some preprocessing to each call, namely the capacity to act upon the source IP (obtained via `bottle.request.remote_addr`). I can specify the preprocessing in each route

```
import bottle

def hello():
    preprocessing()
    return "hello"

def world():
    preprocessing()
    return "world"

def preprocessing():
    print("preprocessing {ip}".format(ip=bottle.request.remote_addr))

bottle.route('/hello', 'GET', hello)
bottle.route('/world', 'GET', world)
bottle.run()
```

but this looks awkward.

**Is there a way to plug the preprocessing function on a global level?** (so that each call goes though it?)

Comment: how about using Decorators

Comment: @realli: wouldn't that be more or less the same (one decorator per function, similar to my `preprocessing()` call)?

Comment: yes, try bottle's Plugin http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/plugindev.html#bottle.Plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use bottle's Plugin

doc here: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/plugindev.html#bottle.Plugin

code example

```
import bottle

def preprocessing(func):
    def inner_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print("preprocessing {ip}".format(ip=bottle.request.remote_addr))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner_func

bottle.install(preprocessing)

def hello():
    return "hello"


def world():
    return "world"

bottle.route('/hello', 'GET', hello)
bottle.route('/world', 'GET', world)
bottle.run()
```